# ASP.NET. Is it possible to find dynamically added WebControl on ItemDataBound?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have `DataList` control:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" OnItemDataBound="dlRequestLayout_ItemDataBound" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" Width="150px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LabelText") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

I'm adding controls on on `ItemDataBound`:

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            WebControl control;
            if (_textbox)
            {
                control = new TextBox();
            }
            e.Item.Controls.Add(control);
        }
    }
```

On `PostBack` I'm searching for `TextBox`, but in `DataList` can find only label.

Is it because of life cycle? How do I get a value of particular text box ?

Thank you

Comment: Try adding an ID to the textbox... Not sure if that'd do the trick, just a thought

Comment: How are you binding data? Only on first page load, or on every postback?

Comment: On button click. So one time. Shoul I do that on each postback ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it because of life cycle?

Yep - essentially you would need to re-add the control on postback for it to be available to subsequent methods/handlers.

An alternative would be to have this textbox as part of your grid and show/hide the textbox with some Javascript - this way it would be available on postback as it was not dynamically added.

Comment: do you mean, that i have to call DataBind() on each postback ?

Comment: I mean you need to re-add that extra control on postback so it is available in the post - that way you can access it where ever it is you want to read its contents.
it would be easier to show/hide it with Javascript through - no need to re-create the textbox's on postback then.

Comment: You would rebind the grid after you changed it so the user can see the changes.

Comment: Thank you... i'm adding a set of control and displaying only required.